# (excel) sumproduct multiplying with another sheet

Tags: excel

i have a little problem with final formulas in one of my column. How to start. maybe i will explain what i have a then what i want.

i have an excel worksheet with 3 sheets. i want to record goods and what are these goods made of. first is sheet called Goods where is possible to put number of goods i want to make. In this case i want to make 1x sandwich1 and at the same time 3x sandwich2. i dont want make sandwich3 this time.

[image: goods sheet]

Second sheet is Matrix sheet where I record every good and what it is made of. This sheet is basic sheet and all other sheets take list of goods (resp. ingredients) from this sheet. Simply when i want to make sandwich1 i look at matrix and know that i need 1x1pc of egg + 1x5g of cheese. And for 3x sandwiche2 i need 3x10g of sausages.

[image: matrix sheet]

Final sheet is called Ingredients. It is a list of used ingredients from Matrix sheet (exactly same order) to make these sandwiches. I want to fill formulas into column B which would go through one ingredient ofter ingredient and count needed amount of it. So it would look into matrix in the same row and where there is some number it would multiply with number of items from Goods sheet. The list of goods is also in the same order as in the matrix sheet.

[image: ingredients sheet]

I hope you understand now what i want and will try to help me. I think there will be SUMPRODUCT, SUMIF and maybe INDERECT functions but i am not that skilled in excel
thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Is the setup of your sheets flexible or does it have to stay exactly like that? If you could transpose the Goods sheet so that each column has a different good and the amounts of each good were all in a single row, then setting up the equations in the ingredients sheet would be a simple matter of filling in the first equation and dragging down the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MMULT` function here - it's an "array formula" which you need to enter in a range. You can do that like this:

In `Ingredients` worksheet enter this formula in `B2`

`=MMULT(Matrix!C2:E4+0;Goods!B2:B4+0)`

[I'm assuming you have a European version of Excel where ; is used to separate arguments]

Now select the whole range `B2:B4`, press F2 key to select formula and hold down `CTRL` and `SHIFT` keys and press `ENTER`. This "array enters" the formula in the range and you should now see curly braces like { and } around the formula and also the correct results.

You cannot change part of that array now, only the whole thing

Note that I'm assuming that the contents of `Goods!A2:A4` will be the same as `Matrix!C1:E1` and in the same order. You can extend the ranges to be as large as you like as long as that principle still holds

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this is an issue of "when all you have is a hammer, every problem is a nail". For reasons known only to you you are using a spreadsheet to solve a problem that databases were made to do. Any solution to this problem in a spreadsheet will be entirely dependent on the integrity of your data - add another column or get things out of order and it will fail.

That said, what you have in your link is effectively a pivot table and what you need is the unpivoted version of this - the instructions for getting this are [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/unpivot-columns-HA104053356.aspx).

When you have that, you can use the various database functions in excel to get your answer.